# Animation player Tree how to use for gdscript (Godot 4.0)

Tags: godot, gdscript

Having issues implementing animation to my script

```
extends CharacterBody2D


const SPEED = 300.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0

var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")


func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    # Handle Jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var direction = Input.get_axis("left", "right")
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        

    move_and_slide()

#having a hard time adding animation tree
```

I tried adding Animation player to the script. and point it to the animation tree yet i cant make it play the animations according to the directions

Answer (score 7):

In principle, you don't need to interact with the `AnimationTree` form your code at all.

What you need is to set an `AnimationPlayer` with the animations you want, then set an `AnimationTree`, make sure that:

- `anim_player` points to your `AnimationPlayer` (it points to nothing by default).
- `advance_expression_base_node` points to something useful. I recommend setting it to your `CharacterBody2D` (it points to the `AnimationTree` itself by default).
- `tree_root` is not empty. I recommend setting to a new `AnimationNodeStateMachine`.
- `active` is set to `true`.

And, of course, you need to make the actual animation tree in the AnimationTree panel that appears on the bottom of the editor.

If you are using an `AnimationNodeStateMachine` as root, you can design a graph with the animations (or blends paces or other state machines) in the AnimationTree panel. For example, you can have an `Idle` animation connect to a `Walking` animation and back.

In the transitions between the animations decide if they must wait for the animation to finish, in which case set their `switch_mode` them to "At End" otherwise let them as "Immediate".

And you can write an expression that will control the transition between nodes in the `advance_expression` property. For example, you can set that `velocity.is_zero_approx()` for transitioning to the Idle animation. And with that Godot will be able to switch animations.

You might also want to set the `xfade_time` and perhaps the `xfade_curve` too also, as these control animation blending.

---

If you really want to manipulate the `AnimationTree` from GDScript start by getting a reference to it in your script. *You can drag it - with CTRL pressed - to your script to have Godot generate an `@onready var` for it.*

For example:

```
@onready var animation_tree:AnimationTree = $AnimationTree
```

With the `AnimationTree` selected you can see which parameters it has in the inspector. Which you can then access with `get` from GDScript (you can copy the  property path from the context menu you get by secondary click on the property in the inspector).

For example:

```
var playback:AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback = animation_tree.get("parameters/playback")
```

In the example we get the playback of the `AnimationNodeStateMachine`, which we can use to tell the state machine to go to the node we want with `travel`. For example:

```
playback.travel("some_state")
```

And, of course, if you need to manipulate the graph you can access the `tree_root` of the `AnimationTree` from code too.